# How To Create Custom Event in Main Form in C#?

Tags: c#, events

I want the following:

```
public static class A
{
    //do something
    UpdateListOnMainForm()
}
```

I already know I can do this by Events, I tried to create a Event but I don't need any parameters, I just want if class A calls the Event the ListView is updating its data.

Can someone help me creating this Event? Or maybe there is a better way?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: At least I'm trying to update a ListView when I've changed the list (other class) from which the ListView takes its data from.

Comment: Are you talking about creating a parameterless method?

Comment: How would the event be triggered?

Comment: Sort of. Well, when I'm trying to create a parameterless method I can't call it from outside because main isn't static.

I want to trigger it like a method call - if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a static class to be able to trigger your main form to update its list view via an event without specifically knowing about the main form, as I understand it. This is how I would do that:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SingletonA.GetInstance.MyEvent += UpdateListView;
    }

    private void UpdateListView(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Update your listview
    }
}

//lazy initialization of singleton - not thread safe see http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/designpatterns/singleton-design-pattern-dotnet for other thread safe version
public class SingletonA
{
    private static SingletonA instance = null;
    private SingletonA() { }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;

    void TellFormToUpdateListView()
    {
        MyEvent?.Invoke(typeof(SingletonA), EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public static SingletonA GetInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new SingletonA();

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer. This seems to be what I wanted.

But how can I call the method `TellFormToUpdateListView()`?

Comment: @Dominik When do you want to call it? You can call it anywhere in the class SingletonA.

Comment: Tried to call it from outside - at least I just need it inside the class and here it works - my fault. Tahnk you very much - works!